# filter df2 by using date column of df1 ..if exist between two date columns and update df1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, range

| FMS_ID | date | code1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18866 | 2022-01-01 | 3103 |
| 18866 | 2022-01-22 | 3103 |
| 18867 | 2022-10-23 | 3103 |
| 18867 | 2022-06-04 | 3103 |

| FMS_ID | Fdate | Tdate | code2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18866 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-21 | 1126 |
| 18866 | 2022-01-22 | 2022-11-01 | 8102 |
| 18867 | 2022-05-03 | 2022-08-01 | 3101 |
| 18867 | 2022-09-04 | 2022-11-01 | 1150 |

I want to take code from df2 and  update  code in df1 but FMS_ID  should match in df2 FMS_ID and date should be between Fdate & Tdate.  Many thanks.

output table: df1

| FMS_ID | date | code1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18866 | 2022-01-01 | 1126 |
| 18866 | 2022-01-22 | 8102 |
| 18867 | 2022-10-23 | 1150 |
| 18867 | 2022-06-04 | 3101 |

Comment: can you add your expected output table?

Comment: added output table ..kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are two of the FMS IDs you gave as the key, a new row will be created for each combination. So FMS_ID is not unique key. I think you are aware of that. If these are ok, you can merge these two df's with **merge** and check the dates.

```
final = df.merge(df2,how='left',on=['FMS_ID'])
final=final[(final['date'].ge(final['Fdate']) & (final['date'].le(final['Tdate'])))].drop(['code1','Fdate','Tdate'],axis=1)

#or

final=final[(final['date'] >= final['Fdate']) & (final['date'] <= final['Tdate'])].drop(['code1','Fdate','Tdate'],axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
    FMS_ID  date    code2
0   18866   2022-01-01  1126
3   18866   2022-01-22  8102
5   18867   2022-10-23  1150
6   18867   2022-06-04  3101
```

Comment: thanks for reply .....yes  FMS_ID with date is unique....i need df1 with updated code (3103  is changed to 8102 ).but now i get other columns of df2

Comment: Dear Clegane..kindly see the three tables modified header also....could you please see...